# Modify the return address of a C function with buffer overflow vulnerability

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to modify the following C program so that the main function will skip the printf("x is 1") line and only print "x is 0".

```
 void func(char *str) {
         char buffer[24];
         int *ret;

         ret = buffer + 28; // Supposed to set ret to the return address of func
         (*ret) += 32; // Add the offset needed so that func will skip over printf("x is 1")
         strcpy(buffer, str);
 }

 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
         int x;
         x = 0;
         func(argv[1]);
         x = 1;
         printf("x is 1");
         printf("x is 0");
         getchar();
 }
```

As the comments imply, the ret pointer needs to first be set to the return address of the function. I then need to add on an offset that will push it over the line I want to skip. I am running this code on a Linux system with 2 x Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.20GHz. I am using gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5) to compile. I'm also trying to use example3.c from this (http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html) link for reference. Here is a disassembly of the main function using gdb:

```
 Dump of assembler code for function main:
    0x0000000000400641 <+0>:     push   %rbp
    0x0000000000400642 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
    0x0000000000400645 <+4>:     sub    $0x20,%rsp
    0x0000000000400649 <+8>:     mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
    0x000000000040064c <+11>:    mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
    0x0000000000400650 <+15>:    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
    0x0000000000400657 <+22>:    mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
    0x000000000040065b <+26>:    add    $0x8,%rax
    0x000000000040065f <+30>:    mov    (%rax),%rax
    0x0000000000400662 <+33>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
    0x0000000000400665 <+36>:    callq  0x4005ac <func>
    0x000000000040066a <+41>:    movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
    0x0000000000400671 <+48>:    mov    $0x40075b,%edi
    0x0000000000400676 <+53>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
    0x000000000040067b <+58>:    callq  0x400470 <printf@plt>
    0x0000000000400680 <+63>:    mov    $0x400762,%edi
    0x0000000000400685 <+68>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
    0x000000000040068a <+73>:    callq  0x400470 <printf@plt>
    0x000000000040068f <+78>:    callq  0x400490 <getchar@plt>
    0x0000000000400694 <+83>:    leaveq
    0x0000000000400695 <+84>:    retq
 End of assembler dump.
```

Using what I've read from the example, my buffer is 24 bytes long and I should add an extra 4 bytes for the SFP size. This would mean I add 28 bytes to get to the return address of <+41>. It then looks like I want to jump to the last printf call at <+73>. This should be an offset of 32. However, when I execute the code, "x is 1" is still printed. I can't seem to find out why. Is there something wrong with my math or assumptions?

Comment: The layout of the stack is not set in stone, the compiler can rearrange its contents (and it can even keep the local variables in the registers without wasting stack space on them). Like Gwyn Evans said, you should disassemble the called function itself, and see how much stack it allocates (and I think your math is off, you have a buffer of 24 bytes plus a pointer variable, which takes 8 extra bytes). Also, see if [this question](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/4363/262) and its related questions are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be an ideal time to get experience with gdb and verify that your expectations regarding the stack and the function return address locations are correct!

I will, however suggest that your modified return address should probably be at <+63>, not <+73>, as you need to run the function setup code (to pass the argument, etc).